# how to return async from select properly?

Tags: c#

```
  var abc= await homeFixtures.Select(async x =>
            {
                var home = _teamService.GetTeam(x.HomeId);                
                return await home.GetSeName();
            });
```

gets the error: "IEnumerable<Task> does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type IEnumerable<Task>' could be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` is used with `Task`. `Select` returns a list of tasks. You need to use [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___) to await all those tasks and retrieve their results eg:

```
var tasks= homeFixtures.Select(async x =>
            {
                var home = _teamService.GetTeam(x.HomeId);                
                return await home.GetSeName();
            });
var abc=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The result returned by `home.GetSeName()` isn't used in `Select` so `await` can be eliminated and the task returned directly:

```
var tasks= homeFixtures.Select(x =>
            {
                var home = _teamService.GetTeam(x.HomeId);                
                return home.GetSeName();
            });
var abc=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```